# Shows error while trying to build signed apk in react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a react native app which runs properly.But when i try to build apk with the command `gradlew assembleRelease` it shows the following error.

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
```

My png images are fine and already tried invalidate cache/Restart in android studio. But still shows the same error. Tried `android.enableAapt2=false` too but seems like its deprecated. Don't know what the problem is.

I'm using:

- Build tool version 28.0.3
- Build Gradle 3.2.1

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712063/build-failing-during-merge-resources-with-android-gradle-plugin-3-3-0

Comment: The issue there uses gradle 3.3.0 but i'm using 3.2.1. Should i upgrade my build gradle?

Comment: you can... but this solution should also work for 3.2.1 as well. just try adding the code in your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Can you tell me which solution of them should i go for. Because there are couples of.

Comment: the one with the tick mark and 16 upvotes

Comment: Still shows the same error. @AnkushRishi

Comment: Try cd android && ./gradlew clean then re-run code again

Comment: Still the same. @AnkushRishi

Comment: I had the same problem. In logs above this error was actual reason of it, in my case it was corrupted image resource. When I changed it, all works fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Invalidate cache /Restart` in file menu in Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes i did try that.

Comment: Did you try generating APK with GUI in Android Studio?

Comment: I want to build a release apk. I don't know how to do that in android studio.

Comment: I do it this way: In Android Studio got to Build on top bar then Generate Signed APk.. Enter everything required, and remember to use same keystore file next time you create build. Let me know if you face issues in these steps.