# Executionfailed':app:mergeDebugResources'.java.util.concurrent:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException:AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building Ionic project for android using cordova. I am running into following error.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
```

I pretty much tried all the solution recommended and none of them worked in my case. I cant even read the log file. Same project I can able to build in macos.

Things I have tried.

- Updated the Gradle to 5.4.1
- remove and added android project
- ionic cordova platform remove android
- ionic cordava platform add android

Updated android studio to 3.4.1

added `resolutionStrategy` to in `platform\android\build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
}
```

added `android.enableAapt2=false` in `gradle.properties`

added `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0` in `project.properties`

Error message I got

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 
aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
```

command i used to build the project: `ionic cordova run android`

- Cordova version 9.0.0
- ionic version 5.0.0
- angular version 4.4.3

Answer (score 1):

try this in your app level gradle file inside dependencies

```
dependencies {
    .....
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
    }
}
}
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   allprojects {
    // Workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/117900475
    // Remove when upgrading to AGP 3.4 or higher.
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
        }
    }
}
```

> [Repo: Michel Gammelgaard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712063/build-failing-during-merge-resources-with-android-gradle-plugin-3-3-0)

Comment: I tried that as well,but didn't work. BUILD FAILED in 1s
C:\Git_Projects\mobile\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.5.0-alpha03-5252756-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed