# Error In Build APK Flutter using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, apk

I want to build APK Flutter with android studio. I also use firestore in this application. When i try to build, i get this error

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: AAPT Process manager cannot be shut down while daemons are in use
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2DaemonManager.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManager.kt:96)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.namespaced.RegisteredAaptService.shutdown(Aapt2DaemonManagerService.kt:61)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.workeractions.WorkerActionServiceRegistry$shutdownAllRegisteredServices$1$1.run(WorkerActionServiceRegistry.kt:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  D:\Compile\ttpproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\book.png: error: failed to read PNG signature: file does not start with PNG signature.

  Command: C:\Users\hunterpama\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\d657dbace268bb20677284d59b1f0de8\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          D:\Compile\ttpproject\build\app\intermediates\res\merged\release \
          D:\Compile\ttpproject\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\book.png
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      89.1s
*******************************************************************************************
The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
*******************************************************************************************
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

here my file for: android\app\build.gradle
and on application id i not left empty. I just do not want to display it here

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
//            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
//        }
//    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

i just wonder is there any confusion in sync with flutter and android. During debug, it works fine. NO error popup

Comment: i have know the reason of it

Comment: Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712063/build-failing-during-merge-resources-with-android-gradle-plugin-3-3-0/54615423#54615423)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590453/1406067

Comment: yeah it works charmly.. source of it is image not correctly png format

Answer (score 0):

i have know the reason of it. it because of image size. but i do not have proper image size for build.

Comment: i had try use image.png that specfically app's icon but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your project to AndroidX.
If you have AndroidStudio 3.2 or greater you can refactor
[image]

Comment: when i try to migrate, it says 'No Usages Found In The Project'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have tried to build your Flutter APK using Android Studio. You need to go to your Flutter console, navigate to your project, and type this is the command line: `flutter build apk --split-per-abi`

Comment: i think there is no different with terminal and command prompt. i try and it say same error.